# How I get a return code from SQL file - if I excuted ISQL?

Tags: batch-file, backup, isql

I execute in a batch script a SQL file to backup my database. I want from the sql file / script a return code to see if is success or not.

I excuted this

```
isql -S %DBSID% -D %DBSID% -U %DBUSER% -P%DBPASS%  -X -i "C:\example\backup.sql" >> "C:\logs\fullbackup.log"
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `isql` sets an `%errorlevel%` or return code but, if it does you can use something like this:

```
isql -S %DBSID% -D %DBSID% -U %DBUSER% -P%DBPASS%  -X -i "C:\example\backup.sql" >> "C:\logs\fullbackup.log"
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (echo error occured) else (echo success)
```

---

**This will simply check for an [`%errorlevel%`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) and [`if`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) it's 'not equal too' `NEQ` '0' then it will simply `echo` "*error occured*" otherwise "*success*".**

*You can experiment with the `if` conditions or if you require more help, you can also refer to the site.*

Comment: In C:\logs\fullbackup.log is a return code from the sql script "backup.sql". 

How is possible to get the last 5 lines from fullbackup.log ?